# Always return undefined using node.js + cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, css-selectors, cheerio

I'm trying to get the img src but I keep getting undefined

```
<table id="video_jacket_info">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <div id="video_jacket">
                        <img id="video_jacket_img" src="link.image.com" border="0"></div>
                    <!-- end of video_jacket -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

My code to get the image always return the `undefined`

```
axios.get(baseUrl).then(response => {
    let $ = cheerio.load(response.data, { ignoreWhitespace: true, xmlMode: true });
      console.log($('table.video_jacket_info > .video_jacket_img').attr('src'));
     // I followed @JJJ comment but still return undefined
      console.log($('table.video_jacket_info .video_jacket_img').attr('src'));
    });

  }).catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: `>` selects the immediate children, but your target is 5 levels down. Try `$('table.video_jacket_info .video_jacket_img')`

Comment: Still returns undefined

Comment: @JJJ I tried your answer but still returned undefined. I edited the question to put your answer.

Comment: The img has an id, not a class. `$('table.video_jacket_info #video_jacket_img')` Although since ids must be unique you could just do `$('#video_jacket_img')` (and if you have more than one you must change it to a class.)

Comment: @JJJ Thanks! it solves the problem, you can put the answer there

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. `>` means "immediate child" in a CSS selector. Whitespace means "any descendent". Remove the `>`.
2. `.` means class. `#` means id. We want the latter here.

After these changes, the selector becomes `#video_jacket_info #video_jacket_img`.

However, since ids are unique, you can simplify the selector to `#video_jacket_img`. The added parent context doesn't disambiguate anything and makes the selector more brittle since the site might change or remove the parent.

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `
<table id="video_jacket_info">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <div id="video_jacket">
          <img id="video_jacket_img" src="link.image.com" border="0"></div>
        <!-- end of video_jacket -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
console.log($("#video_jacket_img").attr("src")); // => link.image.com
```